# Map Retrofit Path parameter value to the returned object?

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I understand how to use Retrofit's Path parameters when defining an API interface.  For example:

```
@GET("/users/{id}/profile")
void getUserProfile(@Path("id") int userId, Callback<UserProfile> callback);
```

And I understand setting up a basic class that allows GSON to automatically map the API response to my desired class.

My question is, does Retrofit support some kind of annotation on a class member that will auto-populate a path value to the member when it does the GSON magic?  For this example, user ID is in the URL path as a Path param but is not in the response and I'd like to have it assigned to my returned object.

Answer (score 0):

My only idea is more of a workaround than an answer: Use two callbacks.  One defined in the interface method and provided by the caller and a second local callback in some helper class that calls the service generated by the RestAdapter.  The local callback receives the actual response, assigns the missing value I want, and feeds the finished object to the callback provided by the caller?  Something like this, for example...but it seems kind of hacky:

```
public void getUserProfile(final int userId, final Callback<UserProfile> callback)
    {
        Callback<UserProfile> cb = new Callback<UserProfile>()
        {
            @Override
            public void success(UserProfile userProfile, Response response)
            {
                userProfile.userId = userId;
                callback.success(userProfile, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error)
            {
                callback.failure(error);
            }
        };

        myService.getUserProfile(userId, cb);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I stick the request info into the callback when I create it. Then when Retrofit calls either the success or failure method that info is available to be used in the success or failure method.

I use Square's Otto event bus along with Retrofit, so my process is this.

1. An activity "Posts" an event object onto the bus.  That event object
   has all the info needed for Retrofit to make its network request.
2. Another object (in my Application class) subscribes to the bus and
   when receives the request event from the bus.
3. I then make a call to my Retrofit api.  As part of that I create a
   Callback object.  That callback object has to implement the success
   and failure methods, but that is not all it can do.  In my case I
   store a reference to the Otto event object in that Callback object.
4. When the network operation is complete, Retrofit calls either method (success or failure) and that reference to the event object (along with the info that was provided to Retrofit) is available.
5. In the success method I access the GSON converted response and then use a setter to set the event object field in the created object. Remember you define the object that GSON creates so you can have whatever fields or methods you like in it.

If you don't use Otto, you can still make use of the same process, just put the info you want to be available to be passed along to your response into your callback in the same manner.

The following is some code pasted from one of my projects to demonstrate what I describe above.

```
@Subscribe
public void onSignup(SignupRequest event) {
    MyLog.p(this,"inside api repo - making signup request");
    mRailsApi.signup(event, new RailsApiCallback<SignupRequest,SignupResponse>(mBus, event, new SignupResponse()));
}

@POST(API_URL + "/signup")
void signup(@Body UserRequestParams requestParams,
        Callback<SignupResponse> tokenParms);


public class RailsApiCallback<T,S extends BaseResponse> implements Callback<S> {
private Bus mBus;
private S mResponse;
private T mRequestEvent;
@Inject PersistData mPersistData;
@Inject @ForApplication Context mContext;
@Inject MyApp mMyApp;

public RailsApiCallback(Bus bus, T requestEvent, S response) {
    super();
    mBus = bus;
    mResponse = response;    
    mRequestEvent = requestEvent;
    mResponse.setRequestEvent(requestEvent);
    Injector.getInstance().inject(this);
}


@Override
public void success(S convertedResponse, Response rawResponse) {
    MyLog.p(this,String.format("response body = %s",rawResponse.getBody()));
    S response = convertedResponse != null ? convertedResponse : mResponse ;
    response.setSuccessful(true);
    response.setRawResponse(rawResponse);
    response.setRequestEvent(mRequestEvent);
    mBus.post(response);

}
```